# Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open() in \htdocs\assists.php on line 2

Tags: php

I am trying to access my gmail account through my localhost. However, I am getting the response:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function imap_open()

Can someone point out what should I do to resolve the issue?

**My Code.**

```
$imap =  imap_open('{pop.gmail.com:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX','aalam@xxxxxxx.com','xxxxxxx3');
```

Comment: But i am trying pop not imap.

Comment: You may be trying a POP account, but you're still using a function `imap_open`

Comment: @PatrickHund can you tell me what i have to use instead imap_open ?

Comment: Just look at the related question linked in the comment above

Answer (score 1):

Who works with NT systems, can open the file `"\xampp\php\php.ini"` to active the `php exstension` by removing the beginning semicolon at the line `";extension=php_imap.dll"`. Should be: `extension=php_imap.dll`

Answer (score 0):

With phpinfo(), you should make sure that php has installed imap model.

Check your php.ini to ensure you have installed imap correctly.