# PHP Imap connection issue

Tags: php

I think this could be a repeated question but I really need help here, I am receiving Fatal error: undefined function imap_open() how ever I have done the necessary changes as following:
1- the semicolon has been removed from extension=php_imap.dll in php.in
2- I have restarted the xampp

but again I face with same issue , anything else to do more:

```
$hostname='{mail.abc.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username='aaa@abc.com';
$password='123456';

$inbox=imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die ('cannot connect to mailserver via imap' .imap_last_error());
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654453/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imap-open-in-php

Comment: yes I gone through this , that is why I have done all the steps again not working

Comment: what is the error you getting??

Comment: Ask Question 


 


 
up vote

0

down vote

favorite



 Fatal error: undefined function imap_open()

Comment: the extension might not be getting loaded, please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43290599/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imap-open-in-htdocs-assists-php-on-li